Is THHN wire the correct wire to use in exterior conduit powering a quick disconnect?
I'm running conduit on the exterior of my house to connect a 10/3 wire to a quick disconnect which will power my mini split AC unit.  Is THHN wire the way to go?  I know per building codes that Romex wire is not recommended to be used in conduit.

FYI, the issue is not "Romex not recommended to be used in conduit". Because it would be perfectly fine indoors (e.g., for PVC 80 or RMC to provide physical protection where needed). The issue is "Romex not allowed in wet areas", and all conduit outdoors is treated as a wet area. Even if there is never any rain, there will be condensation over time and that collects in the conduit, making it wet.

The correct wire for this situation is THWN, which is equally rated for wet environments.
But, luckily, virtually all wire is dual-rated for both THHN and THWN.

Well, these days that's true. On older wire, you have to check.
